# How to stop entering whitespace in textInput React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How to stop entering whitespace in password input field in React Native?

`password` might be any characters including space.

I tried this: **validator.js**

```
const extract = (str, pattern) => (str.match(pattern) || []).pop() || '';

export function removeWhiteSpace(str) {
  return extract(str, '/^\S*$/;');
}
```

**login.js**

```
passwordHandle(value){
  this.setState({
      password:removeWhiteSpace(value)
  })
  console.log(removeWhiteSpace(value))
}
```

**render()**

```
<View style={{paddingBottom:25}}>
  <TextField 
    label='Password'
    type='password' 
    value={password}
    error={errors.password}
    icon
    onChange={this.passwordHandle}/>
  <Image 
    source={require('../../../assets/img/lock.png')}
    style={styles.icon} />
</View>
```

But it doesn't work.
It only executes the '/^\S*$/;' from `removeWhiteSpace`.

Comment: What is your `removeWhiteSpace()` function and why do you call it when value is not a whitespace ?

Comment: i edited now my question.@Dyo

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This simple regex should work using `.replace` function :

```
passwordHandle(value){
   this.setState({
       password: value.replace(/\s/g, '')
   })
}
```

Comment: perfect your answer saved my day thank you so much Dyo

Comment: I have the username. How can I remove the spaces (more than 1space and the space in prefix and suffix in a text). Above will replace all the space. Here if the user has two names for example Jiffan Joe. Here I need two names with a single space in between. Not all spaces

Comment: @sejn maybe you have to use the answer below, use trim()

Answer (score 4):

You can simply validate spaces in your **onChangeText** function like this

```
onChangeText={(text) => {
 if (text.includes(' ')) {
   setText(text.trim()); 
  } else {
   setText(text);
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use trim() from the prototype String object instead if you only care about spaces being entered at the end (or front) of the string.

```
passwordHandle(value){
   this.setState({
       password: value.trim()
   })
}
```

More info about trim(): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim

Comment: trim doesn't work perfect as you can still add whitespace in between string..

Comment: @VaibhavGidde That's why I said "if you only care about spaces being entered at the end (or front) of the string." in my answer. *facepalm*